# Finding smallest multiple in ruby

Tags: ruby

i recently started learning ruby and  im attempting to solve a problem in which i must find the smallest  number that is  divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20(Problem 5 from project euler) i have the following code which keeps constantly running but is as close as i am to solve it, any suggestions as to why it keeps running? thanks in advance

```
class SmallestMultiple
def findMultiple(limit)
    number = 1
    start = 1
    multiple = 0

    while start <= limit do
        if start == limit
            multiple = number
        elsif number % start == 0
            start +=1
        else
            start = 1
            number +=1
        end
    end       
    puts multiple     
end
end

integer = SmallestMultiple.new
puts integer.findMultiple(10)
```

Comment: It's much simpler: `result = (1..20).reduce(:lcm)`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple

Comment: Well, it **is** complicated if you don't know about `lcm`.

Comment: i did not know about 'lcm' since im new to ruby, it good to know about those functions but i was able to make it work with the answers below

Comment: @Eric, one may not know about `lcm`, but one should ask themselves, "Hmm, I wonder if Ruby might have a `lcm` instance method I could use? If so, what would be its receiver?  Well, it must be an integer, which means it would be an instance of `Fixnum` or `Fixnum`'s superclass `Integer`. What would the method be called? As a wild guess, let's try `lcm`. So let's see if there is such a method: `5.method(:lcm)
 => #<Method: Fixnum(Integer)#lcm>` (or `Fixnum.instance_method(:lcm) # => #<UnboundMethod: Fixnum(Integer)#lcm>`)....

Comment: ...This tells us there is such an instance method for `Fixnum`, and that it is defined on `Integer` ([Integer#lcm](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Integer.html#method-i-lcm)), because `Integer` is shown in parenthesis. We could also write `5.method(:lcm).owner #=> Integer`, but, as you see, that's not really necessary. (For methods defined on `Fixnum`, there is no class shown in parentheses: `2.method(:zero?) #=> #<Method: Fixnum#zero?>`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I can see, you are never stopping as when start and limit are equal, you are not adding anything to start nor exiting the loop:

```
if start == limit
  multiple = number
  start += 1 # Let's be sure we exist if we are done
elsif
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When `start` is equal to `limit`, this line gets executed :

```
multiple = number
```

but nothing else happens, so `start` remains equal to `limit`.

You need a `break` or `start += 1` after.

For `limit = 20`, your script then returns `232792560`.

An alternative is to multiply all the primes lower than 20 :

```
2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19
```

you get `9699690`, but some factors are missing. Which one ?

```
[4, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 20]
```

Multiplying `9699690` by `8 = 2*2*2*2` and `3` should cover them all :

```
9699690 * 8 * 3
232792560
```